# Does google cloud text to speech API supports hebrew?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Tried to connect to it in python , it says that it supports hebrew in beta, but it doesn't work when using he-IL language type
any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just heard google added hebrew to their apu, should be released soon

Comment: do you have more details ? What is language name to use with Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Hebrew is not supported.

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices